# How to return arrays instead of object of arrays in .reduce function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm returning data from an API endpoint with six objects. I need to rearrange them so that they are "categorized" by a nested property "slug". Currently it's returning an object with four arrays, so I essentially want to remove the outer object wrapper. I feel like I'm pretty close, just need to make a simple modification that I can't quite wrap my head around.

```
let res = await this.$axios.$get(`${process.env.WP_API_URL}/wp/v2/media`);
const data = res.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const { slug } = item.acf.category;
  (acc[slug] || (acc[slug] = [])).push(item);
  return acc;
}, {});
```

I've tried changing the last argument to an empty array however that just returns one empty array. How do I fix this?

EDIT: Using a suggestion from @Taplar. Here's a screenshot showing the result:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did you try `Object.values(data)` once the logic is done?

Comment: What @Taplar suggests is the way to go. You won't make it without a hassle in a single `reduce()` call, because you'd need to read the slug of the first element in each iteration to know what each group is about. It's most straightforward to make it an object and then pass through `Object.values()`.

Comment: I've updated my original post with a screenshot of the result using `Object.values()`. It's much closer, however there's still an enclosing array and ideally all four of the nested arrays would "move up a level", if that makes sense.

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense. It sounds like you're looking for something like tuple in some other languages. JavaScript doesn't have tuples. An array of arrays is the closest. Or perhaps you want them *sorted* by slug? But that's another story.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to avoid having to do `galleries[0].map()` and would rather do `galleries.map()`

Comment: Maybe you just want to sort these entries instead of grouping them?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean by sorting them? What I was originally looking for was to have an array of image objects per gallery. So if I have four galleries, I would have four arrays.

Comment: Another option is to construct a bigger piece of data with each gallery having its media assigned to it. It really depends what you need.

Comment: `Object.values` will give you 4 arrays.  They will be housed inside an array though.  I'm not sure what the issue is here.  Just that they are all four in an array?  If you don't want them in an array, then break them out into 4 other variables once you get them.

Comment: Just added an answer that was the real culprit behind the nesting issue. I apologize for the rookie mistake, but thank you two for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you can use `Object.values()` co convert your object to an array.

Also, your `reduce()` can be simplified to a single expression:

```js
const data = Object.values(res.reduce((carry, item) => ({
    ...carry,
    [item.slug]: (carry[item.slug] || []).concat(item)
}), {}))
```

Comment: Well that's pretty slick, I like the simplification. I'm still looking for a way to remove the outer array so that all of the nested arrays are directly underneath "galleries".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @RoboRobok and @Taplar, I simplified my `.reduce` function, and realized that once the data has finished processing, I was doing a `.push` to an empty array afterwards, which was causing the unnecessary nested array.